# Highest power draw of MacBook pro 13 inch 2019 Intel ome

Tags: macbook-pro, power

My macbook pro is the one with touch bar and Intel core i5 CPU. What is the highest wattage my laptop can draw and what is the highest AMPERE(5OR 3?) can I make it draw from the charger?

Comment: It comes with a 61W power charger. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Have you checked the technical specs? https://support.apple.com/kb/SP799?locale=en_GB